# How to play hold music from twilio client

Tags: twilio

I want to implement call hold functionality in twilio client and want to put call on mute and play a hold music which should be listen by dialing party.

I have implemented mute functionality but how can I play music from client to calling party??

Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

Twilio evangelist here.

So just to make sure I understand, you want to let someone (lets call them 'Alice') use Twilio client make an outbound phone call, then have her listen to hold music?  How you do this depends on what you want to be happening while Alice is waiting.

One way to do this would be to use the `<Enqueue>` verb to place Alice into a call queue.  Then when you are ready, a second party (lets call him Bob) could `<Dial>` into the queue and be connected to the Twilio.

A second way is to place Alice into a `<Conference>` when she connects and have Bob Dial into the conference.

A third way is to use the `<Play>` verb, setting the loop attribute to zero.  When you application is ready to have Alice move to some other part of your workflow, you use the REST API to redirect Alices call.

If you can provide more info about what kind of call flow you want to create for Alice, I can recommend a more specific solution.

Hope that helps.

Comment: `Twilio.Device.incoming(function(connection) {
    $('#callsid').val(connection.parameters.CallSid)
});`
This is what i am doing but instead of getting caller callsid .. i am getting my own